# Compare HTTP load balacing using HAProxy & Nginx

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, http, haproxy, keepalived

My requirements:

1. Weighted RR load balancing
2. NO need sticky session support
3. NO need SSL
4. NO need HTTP 1.1 to backend

So effectively I just need very simple HTTP load balacing!!

My Boss asked to try HA Proxy, but I am wondering if **HA Proxy is over-kill for me**, I am wondering what are the benefit of using HA Proxy, when compared to the **existing nginx' HttpUpstreamModule**

e.g. (existing nginx config)

```
upstream backend  {
  server backend1.example.com weight=5;
  server backend2.example.com:8080;
  server unix:/tmp/backend3;
}
```

Since I don't use `HAProxy` in the past so I want to listen to your opinion.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/229945/what-are-the-differences-between-haproxy-and-ngnix-in-reverse-proxy-mode/230665#230665

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably add healthcheck's to your list.  I found that the limitations on health checks and lack of visibility into current status made HAProxy a much better fit for me.

Honestly, its VERY lightweight, powerful, and easy to setup.  Just make the jump. :)